# Must be a private route in playframe in order for my program to work

Tags: java, playframework

I need to use some route privately; for example, I want some controller that provide critical services and use a route in another controller to communicate with that class. Should I use play framework to do that or should I use what I had that takes something else like web server to filter some route.

## Example:

```
class CriticalController extends Controller {
    public static Result CriticalService ( Object o){
        // some services
    }
}

class ControllerTwo extends Controller {
    public static Result service (){
        @routes.CriticalControllerOne.CriticalService( "Hello world" );
        // some service
    }
}
```

But I do not want:

```
@routes.CriticalController.CriticalSevice( Object O )
```

to be accessible publicly.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve, but this sounds like a bad idea to me. You should probably reconsider your design. In MVC controllers should not communicate with each other. Make your service a module and call that service module from your controllers.

Comment: @Roman do you know where I can find useful information about MVC design. I want to use this way to hide some JS some service and so on